# Windows11: hide Start window from Taskbar

Tags: c#, taskbar, windows-11

I want my program to hide start window on Win 11 taskbar. What used to work in Win 10:
IntPtr taskBar = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);

```
IntPtr startButton = FindWindowEx(taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, "Start", null);

ShowWindow(startButton, SW_HIDE);
```

However, this does not do much in win11 - I can still see the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: What overall goal are you trying to achieve? I often see people try to do this to prevent people running other programs; That is often best achieved by using the built into Windows concept of kiosk mode rather than trying to mangle the explorer shell via hiding windows.

Comment: Or trying to restrict which programs can run, again better achieved using built-in tools like Application Control

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I actually want to provide my own custom start button and start menu, so basically replace the default one.